# Validation error using Bootstrap buttons

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am new to HTML/PHP/Javascript and the Bootstrap framework...

Here is my code:

```
<form name="Enquiry" method="post" action="query.php">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h5>Choose search type:</h5>
<div id="selector" class="btn-group">
    <button type="button" name="Surname" class="btn btn-default active">Surname</button>
    <button type="button" name="IDNumber" class="btn btn-default">ID Number</button>
    <button type="button" name="FileNumber" class="btn btn-default">File Number</button>
</div>
<br>
<input id="searchbox" name="QD" type="text" size="20"  maxlength="30" pattern="/[A-z]/g" title="0-Only alphabets allowed! No special characters or numbers. Please correct!">
<script>
$('#selector button').click(function() {
    $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
    $getName = this.name;

        switch ($getName) {
            case "Surname":
            document.getElementById('searchbox').value="";
            document.getElementById('searchbox').maxLength="30";
            document.getElementById('searchbox').pattern="/[A-z]/g";
            document.getElementById('searchbox').title="1-Only alphabets and spaces allowed. Please correct!";          
      break;
            case "IDNumber":
            document.getElementById('searchbox').value="";
            document.getElementById('searchbox').maxLength="13";
            document.getElementById('searchbox').pattern="\d+";
            document.getElementById('searchbox').title="2-Only numerical value allowed in the ID field! Please correct";            
      break;
            case "FileNumber":
            document.getElementById('searchbox').value="";
            document.getElementById('searchbox').maxLength="5";
            document.getElementById('searchbox').pattern="\d+";
            document.getElementById('searchbox').title="3-Only numerical value allowed in the file number field! Please correct";           
        }
});
</script>

<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="search" value="Query">
</form>
```

Full code at:
https://jsfiddle.net/o5n5ucm6/7/

What I am trying to achieve:
Depending on the button that a user presses, I set the validation criteria of an input text box using regxp and maxlength etc.

Problem Im having:
When I click the query button (POST method), even if the value matches the regxp, it still throws an error.

Any help and suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

Javascript allows regex literals, so you don't need to quote your lines.

Change this line:
`document.getElementById('searchbox').pattern="/[A-z]/g";`

To This:
`document.getElementById('searchbox').pattern=\[A-z]\g;`

The two lines with this:
`document.getElementById('searchbox').pattern="\d+";`

Need to be changed to this:
`document.getElementById('searchbox').pattern=\d+;`

Comment: Where does it throw the syntax error exactly? It works for me on this side when I use it.